# How to code a simple CSS to make my web content more appealing

Tags: html, css

I need simple CSS codes that can make my page contents more appealing www.alexanderbernhardtlibrary.com

I simply centralise all the text with in-text css

Something similar to the last content on this site http://www.flamytech.com/ (The content with the heading Top Computer Suplier and IT Firm in Lagos Nigeria

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials for basic CSS than can be found with a simple google search. We would much rather see your attempts before giving you the answer without you trying at all.

Comment: Hire a designer. We can't say what will be "more appealing" to you. Aesthetics are a personal thing. Either that, or as haag says above me, follow some beginner tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read [What Not To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Then [edit] your question accordingly and you'll get dramatically more helpful responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this alone but i can to give you some indication if i understood what you wanted to do..

you can create a container div and make some div inside like : 
HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="headline">
    <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
  <div class= "content">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin: 0 15%;
}
.headline {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #444;
}
```

etc...

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out